# Piechart showing fewer slices than the legend

Tags: c#, charts, pie-chart

I'm a student that is still learning C# and I ran into a problem.
I'm trying to make a graphic (pie chart) with 7 different fields and seven different legendas.

I've got this code:

```
private void InitializeChart()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            ChartArea chartArea1 = new ChartArea();
            Legend legend1 = new Legend() 
            {   BackColor = Color.FromArgb(97,97,97), //achtergrondkleur legende
                ForeColor = Color.White, //kleur van tekst in legende
                Title = "Legende grafiek", //titel legende
                TitleForeColor = Color.White}; //kleur titel legende
            pieChart = new Chart();

            ((ISupportInitialize)(pieChart)).BeginInit();

            SuspendLayout();

            //===Pie chart
            chartArea1.Name = "PieChartArea";
            pieChart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
            pieChart.Height = 300;
            pieChart.Width = 300;
            pieChart.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            legend1.Name = "Legend1";
            pieChart.Legends.Add(legend1);
            pieChart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 50);

            //====Bar Chart
            chartArea1 = new ChartArea();
            chartArea1.Name = "BarChartArea";

            AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;      
            this.Load += new EventHandler(StatistiekenForm_Load);
            ((ISupportInitialize)(this.pieChart)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        private void LoadPieChart()
        {
            pieChart.Series.Clear();
            pieChart.Width = 300;
            pieChart.Height = 300;
            pieChart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.Excel;
            pieChart.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            //pieChart.Titles.Add("Overzicht uitgaven");
            pieChart.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            Series series = new Series
            {
                Name = "Overzicht",
                IsVisibleInLegend = true,
                Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(97,97,97),
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
            };
            pieChart.Series.Add(series);

            int teller, prijsje = 50;

            for (teller = 0; teller < 7; teller++)
            {
                series.Points.Add(teller);
                var p1 = series.Points[teller];
                p1.AxisLabel = Convert.ToString(prijsje + "€");
                p1.LegendText = Convert.ToString("legende " + teller);
                prijsje += 50;
            }

            pieChart.Invalidate();
            panelPie.Width = 400;
            panelPie.Height = 400;
            panelPie.Controls.Add(pieChart);
        }
```

Could anybody explain me why I keep seeing SIX slices, but the legenda shows me seven?
You can see the problem in this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/910qq.png

Thank you very much,
Yenthe.

Comment: How is each pie slice given a certain percentage of the whole? In other words, I see your variable `prijsje` being used to create the label, but how is it being used to numerically divide the pie slices?

Comment: Well I've tested that out by giving ALL slices the same value, and it automaticly put them in the right sizes. I believe this is correctly handled by C#?

Comment: See my updated answer below

Comment: For all the people that would run into the same problem, I did find a fix, its not 100% legit but it does the job.
Apparently the 0 from the axis is not the same than the 0 from the pie parts.
The solution:
            
int teller, prijsje = 50;

for (teller = 0; teller < 8; teller++)
{
 series.Points.Add(teller);
 var p1 = series.Points[teller];

 p1.AxisLabel = Convert.ToString(prijsje + "€");
 p1.LegendText = Convert.ToString("legende " + teller);
 prijsje += 100;
}
series.Points.RemoveAt(0);

Comment: Yenthe - See me answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 7 slices. The first one is too small though and you only see a sliver. Try changing this line: `prijsje += 50` to `prijsje += 10`. his should allow you to better see that there are indeed 7 slices.

UPDATED:

I think you are using the `Add` Method incorrectly. I think what you are thinking is that by calling `series.Points.Add(teller);`, that C# is adding a point to `teller` position in the collection. This is actually incorrect.

What its doing is its inserting a point with the value of `teller`. The first one has a value of 0, which is why you aren't seeing it. Then the next one has a value of 1, which is the "100" label. Then the next one has a value of 2 (which is double the size of the one before it..1), which is the "150" label. If you were to cut out the "100" slice and overlay it on top of the "200" slice, you'd probably think by looking at the labels that two "100" slices could exactly fit into one "200" slice. In actuality, three can fit into one. The reason is because the value assigned to the "200" slice is 3.

To fix your problem, You should be using the [Insert method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection.inserty.aspx) instead of `Add`. Try this:

```
for (teller = 0; teller < 7; teller++)
{
    var dp = new DataPoint(prijsje, prijsje);
    dp.AxisLabel = Convert.ToString(prijsje + "€");
    dp.LegendText = Convert.ToString("legende " + teller);
    series.Points.Insert(teller, dp);
    prijsje += 50;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that solution icemanind! And thank you for the explenation, that made it a whole lot clearer. :)
A big, very big, thank you!